# how to detect connection issues to rabbit mq using mass transit?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

how to detect if the message broker configuration is valid or if the connection to the message broker is lost using Mass Transit to RabbitMQ? When publishing messages when RabbitMQ is present does not seems to complain if there is no broker connection right away and seems to recover when the RabbitMQ server comes up. Is there a way to listen in on the connection events and warn if the configuration is not valid?

Comment: Hey! Is there any code/stack trace we can look at? It may help describe what you have tried, what research you have done and your understanding of the technologies so we can get on the same page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use .NET Core and configure MassTransit as per the docs, you can resolve the instance of `IBusHealth` and use it in your service.

The `AddMassTransit` method registers the default instance, which you can ask for the bus health status at any time. That's the method code:

```
    public HealthResult CheckHealth()
    {
        var endpointHealthResult = _endpointHealth.CheckHealth();

        var data = new Dictionary<string, object> {["Endpoints"] = endpointHealthResult.Data};

        return _healthy && endpointHealthResult.Status == BusHealthStatus.Healthy
            ? HealthResult.Healthy("Ready", data)
            : HealthResult.Unhealthy($"Not ready: {_failureMessage}", data: data);
    }
```

As you can see, if you call `busHealth.CheckHealth()` it will return either `Healthy` or `Unhealthy` and in the latter case would also give you the list of failing endpoints.

Since `BusHealth` only monitors the bus itself and all its receive endpoints, you might not get notified when your service failed to publish messages.

You can use the [diagnostics listener](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/monitoring/diagnostic-source.html) or create your own publish or send [observer](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/observers.html#published-messages), which is called before and after publish/send and on any failure.